# Reverse for 'post_list' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 20}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['$']

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm getting this NoReverseMatch error with pk 20 even when i have created only one post in the database.
It doesn't the list all the posts as it should do and it gives this error.

This is the screen shot

[image: 1]

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    

    def publish(self):
        self.published_on = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def approve_comments(self):
        return self.comments.filter(approve_comment=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.author

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('blog.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    approve_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def approve(self):
        self.approve_comment = True
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post_list")

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.text

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', views.PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', views.UpdatePostView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
    path('draft/', views.DraftListView.as_view(), name='post_draft_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/publish/', views.PostPublish, name='post_publish'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/comment/', views.add_comment_to_post, name='comment_new'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/approve/', views.comment_approve, name='comment_approve'),
    path('comment/<int:pk>/remove/', views.remove_comment, name='comment_delete')
]
```

views.py(only the list view)

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post

    context_object_name = 'post_list_content'

    template_name = 'blog/post_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_on__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_on')
```

post_list.html(template that getting the error)

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block body_block %}
<div class="container jumbotron">
<h1>Welome to Social Blog</h1>
{% for post in post_list_content %}
    <div class='post'>
        <h1><a href="{% url 'post_list' pk=post.pk %}"> {{post.title}} </a></h1>
    </div>
    <div class='date'>
        <p>Published on : {{post.published_on|date:"D M Y"}}</p>
    </div>
    <a href={% url "post_detail" %} >Comments: {{ post.approve_comments.count }} </a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
{% endblock body_block %}
```

Can anyone tell me what actually the error it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had not set the primary key to this detail page url:

```
<a href={% url "post_detail" %} >Comments: {{ post.approve_comments.count }} </a>
```

So changed it to

```
<a href={% url "post_detail" pk=post.pk %} >Comments: {{ post.approve_comments.count }} </a>
```

And the above-mentioned solution by Kishan.

Changed

```
 <h1><a href="{% url 'post_list' pk=post.pk %}"> {{post.title}} </a></h1>
```

To:

```
 <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}"> {{post.title}} </a></h1>
```

Comment: No, I have mentioned another thing in that. Including yours because that was not the only problem(I have even mentioned your name). And you can de-rate the answer I don't care about the points I only care about the solution and the knowledge that I acquire .

Comment: Sry for that my bad

Answer (score 0):

in href="{% url 'post_list' pk=post.pk %}"
is a problem there is no variable argument in this url patterns

```
path('', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list')
```

if you can use post detail it contains a variable argument so that works

```
 href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}"
```

cause in url patterns it has int:pk as variable argument

```
path('post/<int:pk>/', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
```

Comment: ya clarified that but i got another error saying : Reverse for 'post_detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$']